# vector.assign() with value in sequence

Tags: c++, std

Is the following well-defined?

```
std::vector<std::string> v{"test"};
v.assign(1, v.at(0));
```

If the old sequence was destroyed before the new one is constructed
the reference passed to `assign` would be invalidated and hence the
program would be ill-formed.

Does the standard mention this case (the
value being part of the old sequence) or something similar anywhere,
making this construct well-formed? I couldn't find anything.

From the copy of Dinkumware's standard library implementation shipped
with VS2010 (`_Assign_n` is what's called internally by `assign`):

```
void _Assign_n(size_type _Count, const _Ty& _Val)
{ // assign _Count * _Val
    _Ty _Tmp = _Val; // in case _Val is in sequence
    erase(begin(), end());
    insert(begin(), _Count, _Tmp);
}
```

The comment

> in case _Val is in sequence

suggests that either the
standard explicitly states that assigning an element that is part of
the current sequence is well-formed, or that Dinkumware's implementation
just tries to be smart ;)

Which one is it?

Comment: I'm surprised they didn't just write `void _Assign_n(size_type _Count, _Ty val)`, but of course VS2010 predates C++11. Nowadays you really shouldn't be taking a `const&` when you need a copy. It prevents moves.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is undefined behaviour, the copied element cannot come from the container itself.

[sequence.reqmts] table 84 (draft n4606)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`at()` returns a reference to the existing value in the container. As such, this is undefined behavior.

You can make this well defined behavior simply by making a copy of it:

```
v.assign(1, (std::string)v.at(0));
```

Comment: That was well-known. The question is whether the standard says something or not about this behavior